# Is there a way to pull changes from a remote Gitlab repo to a local copy using Git Gui?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-bash, git-gui

I've cloned a Gitlab repo (with a series of branches) locally. I've checked out a branch in this repo using the Git Gui client and noticed that there is no option to pull. I've looked around SO and found a workaround that suggests adding a "pull" command under the tools option in the form, "git pull origin". The current branch would be implied as the last argument yet when attempting this workaround, I am met with an error message stating the following. I've even tried adding a prompt for an argument to the aforementioned command but to no avail. I am still met with the error message below.

> You asked to pull from the remote 'origin', but did not specify
> a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
> for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.

With that said, pulling from the Git Bash shell works but I want to avoid having to open the shell and the GUI client just to work with my remote repos.

Does anyone know of any other workarounds that I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Remote` menu and select `Fetch from` <select remote or All>

Go to `Merge` menu and select `Local Merge`, click `Tracking Branch` and select `master` or whatever branch.

Not as elegant as `git pull` if you setup branch tracking.